# What is the best / suggested method to input more than 1 parameter (*val) through Annyang speech recognition library?

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, annyang

Annyang command uses a *val to input values to the callback function. What should I do if I want to input more than one item ?

For example, I want to update a form based on user input. So I could have a command like

```
set Name *val
```

then val would contain the Name value that I could then assign to the field. But if my form has lot of fields writing a command like this for all fields could be tedious. Instead, I could have

```
set *FieldName *FieldVal
```

This command, would return two parameters instead FieldName and FieldVal. If FieldName is valid name of available fields on the page, then I could update the value with FieldVal, or ignore the command.

One way to achieve this, is, ofcourse parse the val to first get the FieldName and then FieldVal from a command like

```
set *val
```

but I dont think it would always result in clean solutions.

is there a suggested method to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is not the "splat" operator (`*`) but the "named-variable" operator (`:`).

Your command will then look like

```
var commands = {
    'set :FormId with :Value':setForms,
}
annyang.addCommands(commands);

function setForm(formId, value){
    if(isValidForm(formId)){
        forms[formId].value = value;
    }
}
```

And now saying "Set foo with bar" will set the forms["foo"]'s value to "bar".

Comment: Great!!. Works, I just ran a fast check, also read thru the docs, very cheekily it mentions the allowance of arguments, the plural being the operative word there.